# Python : choose only users that have purchased more than x element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I need to select only users that have purchased more than x items

For example I have a table where :

```
    users       items
-----------------------
    1            a
    1            b 
    1            c
    1            d 
    2            N  
    2            M
```

I want to have only users who have purchased more than 3 items. In the case exemple I would have only user 1 and not user 2 who have purchased only 2 items.

For now I am using this condition in my sql script which output is the input of my python script but since it takes a long time I was hoping to do it directly in my python script.

Thank you in advance.

Regards,

Comment: Can't you simply import your table into a dataframe and filter the rows?

Comment: I have already imported it, I know that I should groupby user and apply a function to this grouped dataset that select only users with more than 3 purchased items, but I can't see how to write the function since I am not used to use functions in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [filter](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration):

```
df = df.groupby('users').filter(lambda x: len(x['items']) > 3)
print (df)
   users items
0      1     a
1      1     b
2      1     c
3      1     d
```

Another solution with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.groupby('users')['items'].transform('size') > 3]
print (df)
   users items
0      1     a
1      1     b
2      1     c
3      1     d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can groupby by `users` and then count the number of items purchased:

```
In [8]: d = df.groupby('users').size().reset_index(name='items_purchased')

In [9]: d
Out[9]: 
   users  items_purchased
0      1                4
1      2                2
```

and then filter by a mask:

```
In [10]: fil = 3

In [11]: d = d[d['items_purchased']>fil]

In [12]: d
Out[12]: 
   users  items_purchased
0      1                4
```